# Tomcat - Server in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a really basic Spring app which I deploy using mavens tomcat:run command and it works fine. However, I want it to start and deploy to the server which is located in Eclipse 'server' tab. At the moment it looks like it's deploying to a different one?

I have got WTP plugin installed.

Also, here are my dependencies and plugins:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!--BEGIN - Plugins -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat9-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!--END - Plugins -->
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add the server from server tab and then configure the project on the server. Then you simply just right click on the project and select run on server, then your project will run on the server that is defined in the servers tab in eclipse.

Comment: I can do that already, is there any difference if I was to do it using tomcat:run?

I am watching a Spring tutorial and that guy is doing it by using maven.

Comment: By using the tomcat:run it will be using the maven provided embedded server for deploying the application. And there no difference you can use any as per your needs. But basically embedded server are famous with spring boot projects. Advantages is you don’t need an external tomcat to run and deploy your project.

Comment: Can I configure Maven to use the one in server tab instead?

Comment: You need to comment out / remove maven tomcat plugin from Pom and just right click your project run as - run on server. You can have both. Because the one is maven file is embedded and other is external which you are configuring manually.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help.